# can't convert socket received data to float

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a socket client sending some values ​​to my raspberry pi robot but when I receive them I can print the value in the console but I cant convert it to a float. Transmitted data example:
-0.47 or 0.23

raspberry pi code:

```
import socket

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
serverSocket.bind(("192.168.1.182",9090));
serverSocket.listen();

def main():
    
    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = serverSocket.accept();
    dataFromClient = clientConnected.recv(1024)
    data = dataFromClient.decode()
    curve = float(data)
    print(curve)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

client code:

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
clientSocket.connect(("192.168.1.182", 9090));
clientSocket.send(bytes(curve, "utf-8"));
print(curve)
```

The ***curve*** value is a float between 1.00 and -1.00

The error of the server code is: **ValueError: could not convert string to float:**

examples for curve value:
-0.33
0.75
0.25
-0.58

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948412/sending-a-float-integer-over-a-socket) help at all?

Comment: printing out the value of `data` itself should be useful for debugging. Also, do you get an error or anything? Like, what happens if you run this?

Comment: Can you post the error of the server program ?

Comment: The error of the server code is : ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Perhaps you could add `print(data)` before the error to check what the server receives.

Comment: `curve` is not defined in the client code (?)

Comment: The server receives exactly the data that is transmitted from the client

Comment: Please update your question with some examples of the `curve` variable and the data the client sends and the server receives.

Comment: You are converting a number to a string, which may seem straightforward, but it's not. The length of the string depends on the value, and that makes the approach inconvenient. Using https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html would allow you to send and receive fixed size data.

Comment: But if `curve` is not defined on the client side then your server is probably receiving garbage...(?)
(You had to `import socket` in each code snippet so I guess these are not within the same file)

Also `curve` is a local variable restricted to the scope of the `main` function on the server side. It's unclear where it's coming from on the client side

Comment: curve is defined earlier in the program

Comment: Ok, I see some sample values, but what does the client send and what does the server receive?

Comment: Please share the entire relevant code - like the question @tevemadar linked to in a comment above (actually quamrana first linked it)

Comment: The server receives exactly the data that is transmitted from the client like 0.34

Comment: The code works on my machine for sending a single number by the way, just needed a `str(curve)` on the sending side. It doesn't work with multiple numbers as it will read them (all or at least many) in a single step, and then either decode as a single "long" number (like -0.33 and 567 becoming -0.33567), or die on having negative signs in the middle (like -0.33 and -567 becomes a "-0.33-567" string, and then `float()` dies)

Comment: i managed to get it working by modifying client code to **clientSocket.send (bytes(str(curve), encoding="UTF-8"))**  and server code to **data = dataFromClient.decode("UTF-8")
 curve = float(data)**

Comment: if you resovled problem then you could put it as answer below. and later you can mark you answer as accepted. People will see that this problem is resolved.